# Sot closure of the unit ball of a subalgebra of $B(H)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^* -$ subalgebra of B(H) and $S$ be the closed unit ball of $A$.

1- $S$ is convex and bounded, so $ S = weak^* -cl ~S$. (Is it correct?)

2- By the Kapalansky density theorem, we have $sot-cl~ S = (wot-cl~A)_{\|.\|\leq 1}$, and also I know that $sot-cl ~S = w^*-cl~S$.

From 1,2, I conclude that $S = (wot-cl A)_{\|.\|\leq 1}$ which is not correct. Where is my mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1 is not correct. On a  ball, weak $^*=$ wot. Hahn-Banach says that the **weak** and norm closures agree on a bounded convex set.

Comment: But on unit ball of $B(H)$, weak and weak* topology coincide. Is not it? because of it I claim 1.

Comment: Of course not. If they did, then the unit ball would be weak-compact, and then $B(H)$ would be reflexive. So you would have weak $=$ weak$^*$.